# How to export report to XPS document in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, export, report, signature, xps

I would like to export and save a report as XPS document for the purpose of adding Signature later on.

N.B: i m viewing my report in ReportViewer

I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GemBox spreadsheet](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet) ,It's free to use(there are paid versions also)

Assuming you have your report in a datatable or in a datagridview.Then you can use this code to export your datagridview to a .xps file :

```
 Imports GemBox.Spreadsheet
 Imports Gembox.Spreadsheet.Winformutilities

    Dim ef = New ExcelFile()
    Dim ws = ef.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1")
    DataGridViewConverter.ImportFromDataGridView(ws, Selected.dg2, New ImportFromDataGridViewOptions() With {.ColumnHeaders = True})
    ef.Save(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
```